# Grabbing the "other" value in a Set of size 2

Tags: java, set, assert

I'm working on a web app that has a switch account feature. When you click the switch account link, a box appears with a dropdown with a list of all the account you can switch to.

For cases where the user has exactly two accounts, I intend to not show the box with the dropdown, and instead just switch to the other account.

This is really easy to do, but the code to obtain the "other account" is not terribly elegant. I was hoping someone had an idea to clean it up.

```
public boolean hasExactlyTwoAccounts() {
    return this.accountIdMap.size() == 2;
}

/**
 * @return the account Id that is not currently selected
 */
public String getOtherAccountId() {
    assert this.hasExactlyTwoAccounts();

    for (String accountId : accountIdMap.keySet()) {
        if (!this.selectedAccountId.equals(accountId)) {
            return accountId;
        }
    }

    // worst case scenario
    return selectedAccountId;
}
```

I rarely ever use asserts, but it did seem appropriate here. These methods are being called from a JSP, with the getOtherAccountId() method only ever being called if the hasExactlyTwoAccounts() method is true. So the use of assert here is simply to future proof this method from another developer using it improperly.

Thoughts anyone? First, on a more elegant way to grab the other key in the map, and second, on my use of an assert and on asserts in general.

**EDIT** I'm open to the use of external libraries... which is pretty much what I mean by elegant.

Something almost like this:
http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.github.ansell.pellet/pellet-common/2.3.3/org/mindswap/pellet/utils/BinarySet.java

Comment: Remember that `asserts` can be disabled by a compiler option, and usually are disabled in production code. You're better off throwing some kind of exception to indicate a mis-use of the method, like maybe an `UnsupportedOperationException` or `IllegalStateException`. Assertions are mainly useful for debugging to catch any flaws in the algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

I think that your method of getting the other account id is perfectly fine and easily understood.  Other methods are likely less clear and less efficient (creating other collections etc).

I would actually go so far as to say that there is no more elegant solution, at least not overly so, without using 3rd party libraries.  Even with 3rd party libraries (e.g. Guava), the solution would not really be any superior and would likely be less efficient (e.g. filtering the set of taking a set difference).

Only change you should consider is to throw an exception if no other account id is found (your worst case).  The assert should take care of that, but then there is no need for your worst case return (other than to make the code compilable).  I suggest replacing it with a thrown exception.

EDIT:

Since you mention that you are open to external libraries, then this may be the solution with the fewest lines of code (not necessarily the most elegant though), using Google Guava:

```
Sets.filter(accountIdMap.keySet(), Predicates.not(Predicates.equalTo(selectedAccountId))).iterator().next();
```

Whether that is considered elegant or not is in pretty much a matter of opinion, I am not actually sure where I stand on it.

Comment: Ya, I thought of predicates. Our project uses apache commons which supports predicates. I tend to agree, fewer lines of code != elegant. robust/easy to understand code == elegant.

Answer (score 1):

No opinion on assert, but a question: What will be the effect on your application of an uncaught assert here, and is that something you want? Sometimes it's better to log an error for later review, and give a reasonable answer that lets the program go forward.

Here's a one-liner that returns the "other" key in a hash. It deletes the key you don't want, then returns the remaining key. It copies the hash before deleting; that's what {}.update(hash) is for. And since delete doesn't return the hash, tap is used to keep everything in one line.

```
1.9.3-p429 :001 > hash = {a: 1, b: 2}
 => {:a=>1, :b=>2} 
1.9.3-p429 :002 > {}.update(hash).tap{|h|h.delete(:a)}.keys[0]
 => :b 
1.9.3-p429 :003 > hash
 => {:a=>1, :b=>2} 
1.9.3-p429 :004 >
```

BTW, you're probably using "this" more than you need to.

Comment: Ya, it's a habit. A codebase I maintain has a bunch of huge object inheritance structures (ugly stuff). We try to use this and super for code readability. This particular class is fairly stand alone and small, so it's overkill to use the keyword.. agreed.

Answer (score 0):

I think this looks a lot better

```
/**
 * @return the account Id that is not currently selected
 */
public String getOtherAccountId() {
    if(!this.hasExactlyTwoAccounts()) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("You cannot call this method if the accountIdMap is not a size of 2");
    }

    Set<String> accountIds = new HashSet<String>(this.accountIdMap.keySet());
    accountIds.remove(this.selectedAccountId);

    return accountIds.iterator().next();
}
```